# Provider in `didChangeDependencies` does not update data

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm initializing the data in my provider in `didChangeDependencies` in the parent widget.

```
  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    final provider = Provider.of<NewArrivalsProvider>(context);
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection(CurrentUser.getCurrentUser().uid).doc('newArrivals').get().then(
      (snapshot) {
        Map<String, dynamic> data = snapshot.data();
        provider.init(data);
      },
    );
  }
```

Then updating the data in the child widget.
The change in the data is does not persist however.

```
Switch(
  value: item.value,
  onChanged: (state) => provider.update(key: item.key, state: state),
)
```

Only one switch changes value at a time.

```
class NewArrivalsProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  Map<String, dynamic> _items = {};
  Map<String, dynamic> get items => _items;
  int get length => _items.length;

  void init(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    _items = data['mapUrls'];
  }

  void update({@required String key, @required bool state}) {
    _items.update(key, (value) => value = state);    
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Since this is the first I used Provider in the didChangeDependencies method, I'm suspecting that's where the error is. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it.
I changed the provider declaration in the `didChangeDependencies` to

```
final provider = Provider.of<NewArrivalsProvider>(context, listen: false);
```

When `listen: true`, this line listens to the changes I make to the data.
Then it downloads the data again from Firestore (which is set to false initially)

The change to `listen: false` makes line run only when the user navigates to the page and does not update every time I change the data